# How to configure axios to request WebAPI with auth?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, axios

I have a local ASP.Net FrameWork WebAPI server with the following controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        [AuthorizationFilter]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
}
```

I created an `AuthorizationFilter` attribute to handle authorization (only for GET with no id action):

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext ctx)
        {
            if(ctx.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
            {
                ctx.Response = ctx.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            } else
            {
                string authenticationString = ctx.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
                string decodedAuthString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationString));
                string username = decodedAuthString.Split(':')[0];
                string password = decodedAuthString.Split(':')[1];
                // assume that I have checked credentials from DB
                if (username=="admin" && password=="root")
                {
                     // authorized...
                } else
                {
                    ctx.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Also, I modified `Web.config` to allow `CORS`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    ...
 </system.webServer>
```

I ran the server and tried to get `/api/values/1` from the browser, and it worked.
[image: WebApi working fine]

I then tried to access the action that requires authorization: `/api/values` :
[image: WebApi did not work]

I used Insomnia to send requests and test CORS. First I tried the action that doesn't require authorization:
[image: Insomnia working fine]

Then I tried the action with authorization:
[image: Insomnia no-auth not working]

Then I tried the same action but after adding the authentication username and password, and that worked out fine:
[image: Insomnia auth working]

After this point, I knew my webapi is configured correctly, so I tried to pull data from a React app using axios:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:50511/api",
});

const response = await api.get("/values/1");
console.log(response.data);  // works fine: I get "value" as expected
```

And now, the final step, to configure axios to request the action that requires authentication:

```
const api2 = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:50511/api",
  auth : {
      username: "admin",
      password: "root"
  }
});

const response = await api2.get("/values");  // causes a network exception
```

[image: axios not working]

The reported error is strange, since it talks about CORS. I don't get it. If there shall be an error, it can imagine it being an error related to authorization. Not CORS. Not after being able to use axios to pull data from the action that has no authentication filter.

I examined the request header to make sure that it was configured with the correct Authorization parameter:
[image]

I also tried to use axios in different ways:

```
const response1 = await axios.get("http://localhost:50511/api/values",{
    auth: {
        username: "admin",
        password: "root"
    }
});

const response2 = await axios.get("http://localhost:50511/api/values",{
    headers: {
       Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("admin:root"),
    }
});
```

Both of these attempts did not work.
Then I tried again, but this time passing an empty object as the second parameter to the axios call:

```
const response3 = await axios.get("http://localhost:50511/api/values", {}, {
    auth: {
        username: "admin",
        password: "root"
    }
});

const response4 = await axios.get("http://localhost:50511/api/values", {}, {
    headers: {
       Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("admin:root"),
    }
});
```

Again, none of these attempts worked. What am I don't wrong?